# How do I translate an application that is protected and cannot be translated by AllTrans Xposed Module?

Tags: apk, localization, protected-apps

I've been trying to translate this application using AllTrans, yet I don't know how to do it by extracting and recompiling the APK?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Lens.. it can translate text directly from your screen. Pretty awesome.

Hope it helps